# Index error- Works in one part of my code, not another

Tags: python, encryption, indexing, cryptography

I keep getting an index error:

```
User_input is 0
Key is 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Theo_2\Google Drive\Computer science\Encryption and decryption work\Cipher 2\Cipher 2.5.0 alpha1.py", line 62, in <module>
    Test_algorithm(5)
  File "C:\Users\Theo_2\Google Drive\Computer science\Encryption and decryption work\Cipher 2\Cipher 2.5.0 alpha1.py", line 49, in Test_algorithm
    Encrypt(User_input)
  File "C:\Users\Theo_2\Google Drive\Computer science\Encryption and decryption work\Cipher 2\Cipher 2.5.0 alpha1.py", line 21, in Encrypt
    ref_for_output = Master_Key.index(User_input[Count]) + Master_Key.index(Key[Count])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

### The User_input is 0 part is me testing

Basically the following code is a rewrite of something I wrote to encrypt and decrypt using a keyword. This version isn't finished, all my functions are defined, including one to test every possible value, but I haven't started any interface yet.
Anyway my code is as follows:

```
import time
Master_Key = "0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!\"#£$%&'()*+,-./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n\r\x0b\x0c"
global Output
Output = ""
global Key
Key = ""
def Compatibility_check(Key):
    while Key == "":  
        print("Your key cannot be blank")
        Key = input("Please input a new key: ")
    while len(Key) > len(User_input):
        Key = Key[:-1]
    while len(Key) < len(User_input): 
        Key += (Key[Temp])
        Temp += 1

def Encrypt(User_input):
    Count = 0
    Output = ""
    while Count <= len(User_input):\
        ref_for_output = Master_Key.index(User_input[Count]) + Master_Key.index(Key[Count])
        if ref_for_output > len(Master_Key):
            ref_for_output -= len(Master_Key)
        Output += Master_Key[ref_for_output]
        Count += 1
        print(Output)

def Decrypt(User_input):
    Count = 0
    Output = ""
    while Count <= len(User_input):
        ref_for_output = Master_Key.index(User_input[Count]) - Master_Key.index(Key[Count])
        if ref_for_output < 0:
            ref_for_output += len(Master_Key)
        Count += 1
        Output += Master_Key[ref_for_output]

def Test_algorithm(Null):
    fail, Input_Counter = False, 0
    while Input_Counter <= len(Master_Key):
        User_input = Master_Key[Input_Counter]
        print("User_input is " + User_input)
        Key_Counter = 0
        Input_Counter += 1
        while fail == False:
            while Key_Counter < len(Master_Key):
                Key = Master_Key[Key_Counter]
                print("Key is " + Key)
                Encrypt(User_input)
                print("The encrypted value is " + Output)
                Decrypt(Output)
                print("The decrypted value is " + Output)
                if Output == User_input:
                    print("The encryption and decryption of " + str(User_input) + " with the key " + str(Key_Counter) + " results in " + Output)
                    print("pass")
                else:
                    print("fail")
                    print("The encryption and decryption of " + str(User_input) + " with the key " + str(Key_Counter) + " results in " + Output)
                    fail = True
                Key_Counter += 1

Test_algorithm(Nothing)

##Key = "abcdefghijklmnop"
##User_input = "12345"
##Compatibility_check(Key)
##Encrypt(User_input)
##print(Output)
```

This is a refinement of an old script, which worked but could really do with improvement. The reason I am rewriting it is that I want to output encrypted values to a file and then re-read and decrypt them upon user request.
I hope you can help- Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the variable User_input is the string "0" and therefore this fails when Count is 1 since the index starts at 0 and User_input[1] is the second letter of the string.

You probable want to start by changing this:

```
while Count <= len(User_input):
```

to this:

```
while Count < len(User_input):
```

Comment: Count is never more than 0, the Encrypt function runs as followed:def Encrypt(User_input):
    Count = 0
    Output = ""
    while Count < len(User_input):
        ref_for_output = Master_Key.index(User_input[Count]) + Master_Key.index(Key[Count])
        if ref_for_output > len(Master_Key):
            ref_for_output -= len(Master_Key)
        Output += Master_Key[ref_for_output]
        Count += 1
        print(Output)                                                    I am calling the test function It encrypts each character in Master_key with every other character in Master_key

Comment: This means that count will never be higher than 0 (Or it shouldn't be) as both the User_input and Key never have a length longer than 0 (In indexes)

Comment: Even if I change the index to 0 instead of count in  ref_for_output = Master_Key.index(User_input[0]) + Master_Key.index(Key[0]) It throws the same error

Comment: Ah, ok. Another problem that I see is that Key needs to be marked as global in the method scope where you modify it, not in the file skope. So, this line: Key = Master_Key[Key_Counter] is actually making a new variable Key and not modifying the global, which was probably your intent. Try adding global Key to your Test_algorithm method.

Comment: Ok by adding global Key above Key = Master_Key[Key_Counter] I get an extra line of output- Namely- "The encrypted value is"

Comment: I have had this before actually- my encrypt function isn't outputting anything

Comment: Wait actually. I need to learn to read. I am getting an error in decrypt because Encrypt isn't outputting anything. Well thats progress

Comment: By changing <= to < in decrypt as I did in encrypt I have got the testing loop to run. However it is clearly not working as I get similar to this with each one The encrypted value is 
The decrypted value is 
fail
The encryption and decryption of 0 with the key 0 results in 
Key is 1
1

Comment: You need to do a similar global thing with your output variable. In general, there appear to be some issues with this code. 
Since we have fixed the problem you asked about, please mark the this answer, thanks. :)

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Encryption and decryption is working fine. I may just re-write the testing loop as its a mess anyway.

Comment: And yes I see what you mean now. I am so stupid- Encrypt was outputting a value but I couldn't print it as Output was not global. Thanks for your help. It was much simpler in Java haha just tell it to reference something and it would.

Comment: My loop now works. Thanks again. I honestly never thought about using globals inside functions.